# Is it possible that text editor could contain character values after writing a double value into the file

Tags: binaryfiles, text-editor

If you write a double value into a binary file and open that binary file in a text editor. Is it
possible that you might see the string ABCDEFGH in the file ?

Comment: You could try it and see.  I'm assuming by double you mean a [64-bit floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  If the bit pattern matched exactly the ASCII bit pattern for the characters "ABCDEFGH", then yes, you'd see that result.

Comment: That depends on how you save/encode/serialize the `double` value into a byte sequence. How do you save/encode/serialize the `double` value? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using Java to experiment this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although the value of the double that results in `ABCDEFGH` will vary between systems.

Most modern computers use a little endian representation for both integers and IEEE floating point numbers. In this case, the value of the double will be: `1.5839800103804824e+40`.

For systems using big endian integers and big endian IEEE floating point numbers: `2393736.541207228`

On systems that use different endianness for their integers and floating pointer numbers, it doesn't appear to be possible to do this. (`ABCDEFGH` corresponds to an alias of zero, so you can't necessarily convert the other way)

And apparently, there are some ARM chips out there that use little endianness overall, but swap the words of their double precision numbers. On such a system, `ABCDEFGH` could be produced with `710524627902859500000.0`.

Edit: and all of this assumes that your text editor is using an ASCII-compatible text encoding.